# Changing DNS of website to point to another website

Tags: apache, redirects, dns

I have two website `abc.com` and `newabc.com`. Both are on different web servers.

I want to shut down `abc.com` and make sure that I want to send its requests to `newabc.com`.

I am shutting down the servers of `abc.com`. I came to know that this can be done by doing some changes at the DNS of `abc.com`.

Can I point DNS of `abc.com` to `newabc.com`.

Can someone tell how doing that?

Comment: You can point the DNS `A` records at your new server. How you do that is dependent on your ISP or DNS provider. You need to configure your new web server to respond to requests to the old name as well. Once again, how you do it is system dependent.

Comment: @MikeW. Thank you for the reply. Can you explain what exactly it means by system dependent.

Comment: different ISPs use different systems to manage their hosted accounts. Even where two ISPs use the same system (cPanel, for example) there may be differences in what is included in your package. As a result it's not possible to give specific instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The below link would help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144929/domain-redirect-to-another-domain-with-dns

Also the simplest way,

You could do it by placing a normal index.html in abc.com with below single line of code

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://www.newabc.com/">
```

Where 2 is the number of seconds. You could make it to 0 also.

Comment: This will only work if the old domain continues to exist, along with its hosting arrangements.

Comment: What if the domain expires and some one else takes the same domain? How would you do it if the domain doesn't belong to you? How would you redirect the user if I enter www.abc.com if it belongs to some one else? Better to transfer the domain www.abc.com to the same hosting provider where www.newabc.com and make it a shared hosting if you are not interested in spending more infrastructure on maintaining www.abc.com

Comment: If the domain expires you have no control, but the domain can be maintained without speciic hosting arrangements if the hosting for the new domain is set to service the old domain too.

Comment: Agreed, so the answer is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144929/domain-redirect-to-another-domain-with-dns and I don't think so setting up the infrastructure for having one index.html in shared hosting would be too big.